# element-ui's $notify encounters special character style disorder

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

When I use element-ui's $notify, when I encounter special character styles, the display will be confused. Does anyone have any pointers on how to solve it?

```js
<template>
<div>
   <el-button
     plain
     @click="open2">
     does not close automatically
     </el-button>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   methods: {
     open2() {
       this.$notify({
         title: 'Tips',
         message: 'The comparison version MP16_SM6125_10.0_202101121904_user is under analysis, please check back later. ',
         duration: 0
       })
     }
   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a style cover yourself

```js
this.$notify({
         title: 'Tips',
         message: '<div style="word-break: break-all;">Compared version MP16_SM6125_10.0_202101121904_user is under analysis, please check back later. </div>',
         duration: 0,
         dangerouslyUseHTMLString: true
       })
```